# Rails Rspec Factory Feature Tests: Trait not registered

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

`rails 5.0.4`  `ruby 2.5.1`  `rspec 3.7` `capybara`

I need some help on creating factories and how to use them in my feature specs.  I keep running into the same issues and when I think I have it figured out, I run into the same problem again.

Models:

```
customer.rb
 has many jobs

job.rb
 belongs to customer
 has_many hours

hour.rb
 belongs to job
```

Factories:

```
#customer.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer, :class => Customer do
    name "abc construction"
    contact "John"
    street "101 Main street"
    city "Anywhere"
    state "NY"
    zip "12345"
    phone "123-555-4567"
  end
end

#job.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job, :class => Job do
    customer_id
    street "55 first str"   
    city "Anywhere"
    state "NY"
    zip "12345"  
    phone "123-456-7890"
    created_at Time.now
    updated_at Time.now
    description  "Test Job"
    name "house repairs"    
  end
end

# hour.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :hour, :class => Hour do
    job_id
    date_worked Date.today  
    hours 1
    description "test"   
  end
end
```

Hours feature spec

```
# hours_spec.rb
context "edit form" do
    before(:each) do
      customer=FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
      job=FactoryGirl.create(:job, :customer_id => customer.id)
      hours=FactoryGirl.create(:hour, :job_id => job.id)

      visit edit_hour_path(:id => hours.id)
    end
    scenario "update messages shows" do
      within('form') do
        fill_in 'hour_description', with: 'testing'
      end
      click_button("Update Hours")
      expect(page).to have_content("You updated the record")
    end
  end
```

Run the hours spec tests

```
rspec spec/features/hours_spec.rb
...
.....Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.9.1 , codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:44465
.DEPRECATED: Capybara::Helpers::normalize_whitespace is deprecated, please update your driver
.F

Failures:

  1) Hours edit form update messages shows
     Failure/Error: job=FactoryGirl.create(:job, :customer_id => customer.id)

     ArgumentError:
       Trait not registered: customer_id
     # ./spec/features/hours_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.86646 seconds (files took 1.24 seconds to load)
8 examples, 1 failure
```

If I change my jobs factory to have a value for customer_id, I get a similar error, but with a number (488). maybe what it sees as the customer_id?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job, :class => Job do
    customer_id FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
    ...
end
```

```
rspec spec/features/hours_spec.rb

Failures:

  1) Hours edit form update messages shows
     Failure/Error: job=FactoryGirl.create(:job, :customer_id => customer.id)

     ArgumentError:
       Trait not registered: 488
     # ./spec/features/hours_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong?  What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FactoryGirl has recently been renamed FactoryBot and removed support for assigning static values to properties due to the issues around dates with that (all dates/times in your factories would always be assigned as the time/date the code is read, not when it was actually run. You should update, and also use associations in your factories instead of directly assigning ids.

```
#customer.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :customer, :class => Customer do
    name { "abc construction" }
    contact { "John" }
    street { "101 Main street" }
    city { "Anywhere" }
    state { "NY" }
    zip { "12345" }
    phone { "123-555-4567" }
  end
end

#job.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :job do # class defaults to one matching the factory name
    customer # association type defaults to one matching the name
    street { "55 first str" }   
    city { "Anywhere" }
    state { "NY" }
    zip { "12345" }  
    phone { "123-456-7890" }
    # created_at and updated_at are handled automatically 
    # created_at { Time.now }
    # updated_at { Time.now }
    description  { "Test Job" }
    name { "house repairs" }    
  end
end
```

job = FactoryBot.create(:job) # this will automatically create an associated customer

job = FactoryBot.creatE(:job, customer: FactoryBot.create(:customer, name: 'abc')) # will use the customer passed as the associated customer

Comment: Thank you! I will work on changing to FactoryBot. In the mean time, I figured out how to make my code work with FactoryGirl with associations like you pointed out.  Just using `customer` not `customer_id` in my `job factory`
```

Comment: @JohnCowan yes, that is using associations like I mentioned in the other answer and show in this answer

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a hash to the factory methods, not assign local variables

```
job=FactoryGirl.create(:job, customer_id: customer.id)
```

although since you have a belongs_to association between job and customer you should look into associations in factory_girl  (now called factory bot)  and have `customer` in your factory rather than customer_id https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working. I should have proof-read my post,  I must have copy-pasted something I was trying.  I am using `job=FactoryGirl.create(:job, :customer_id => customer.id)'  I edited my initial post.